# File Upload is not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, upload

I'm trying to upload a file using FileUpload, and it doesn't work. After I click the button, it reloads the page, but the image is not saved

Below code is from microsoft, but still not working

```
protected void uploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Boolean fileOK = false;
            String path = Server.MapPath("~/Sources/images/");
            if (imageUpload.HasFile)
            {
                String fileExtension =
                    System.IO.Path.GetExtension(imageUpload.FileName).ToLower();
                String[] allowedExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" };
                for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                    {
                        fileOK = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fileOK)
            {
                try
                {
                    imageUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path
                        + imageUpload.FileName);
                    statusUploadLbl.Text = "File uploaded!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    statusUploadLbl.Text = "File could not be uploaded.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                statusUploadLbl.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
            }
    }
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain what "not working" means exactly.

Comment: After I click the upload button, it refreshes the page and the file is not saved into the directory

Comment: Yeah so set a breakpoint in your `catch` clause and inspect the exception.

Comment: I set a breakpoint to try, catch and else and it doesn't go thru any of the breakpoints..